# How to pass dotenv variables to npm script?

Tags: node.js, bash, environment-variables, npm-scripts, dotenv

I need to read a variable from `.env` file and pass it to an npm script (or make it available for the script).

I tried it like this with `dotenv` library:

```
dotenv -e .env -- graphql-faker api-extension.gql --extend $ORIGINAL_SCHEMA
```

And I got an error:

> a missing argument: extend

However, if I make 2 npm scripts in `package.json`, it works:

```
"faker": "graphql-faker api-extension.gql --extend $ORIGINAL_SCHEMA",
"graphql:start-faker": "dotenv -e .env -- yarn run faker",
```

How to achieve it in one-line (within one npm script)?